# Explanation of spectral residual algorithm for outlier detection

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, outlier

I've been reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03821.pdf for spectral residual outlier detection, but I don't quite understand it. Specifically, in the [implementation](https://github.com/y-bar/ml-based-anomaly-detection) there are three variables that determine how to algorithm will find outliers:

```
# less than period
amp_window_size

# (maybe) as same as period
series_window_size

# a number enough larger than period
score_window_size
```

Also, the only documentation that I could find on the algorithm was [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.timeseries.srcnnanomalyestimator?view=ml-dotnet#methods).

Can anybody familiar with the paper, or with time series, explain how the algorithm works, and how these 3 variables determine how outliers are detected?

Answer (score 1):

Can I make a slightly more general observation?

Look at the datasets they test on, and read [a].

There is no read evidence that this idea works, so why bother to implement it?

[a] Current Time Series Anomaly Detection Benchmarks are Flawed and are Creating the Illusion of Progress  https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.13807

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).